# Function to loop through nc_open: Calls: lapply -> FUN -> nc_open r

Tags: r, function, loops, lapply

I'm trying to simplify my scripts, and therefore trying to loop through a set of netcdf-data I have. There are five I have, outside the loop this command works:

```
data <- nc_open('/specific_1/data.nc')
data_var <- ncvar_get(data, "var")
data_var <- data_var[50:164]
```

Now, trying to loop through the five sets I tried the following:

```
dflist <- c("1","2","3","4","5")

lapply(dflist, function(df) {
data <- nc_open(paste("'/specific_",df,"/data.nc',",sep=""))
data_var <- ncvar_get(data, "var")
data_var <- data_var[50:164]
NULL
```

})

I gives me the error

```
Error in R_nc4_open: No such file or directory
Error in nc_open(paste("'/specific_",  : 
Error in nc_open trying to open file '/specific_1/data.nc',
 Calls: lapply -> FUN -> nc_open
 Execution halted
```

I mean, it is fairly obvious that r won't find my file. But why? It puts the path together correctly, no (Error in nc_open trying to open file '/specific_1/data.nc')? There probably is an easy solution, but I haven't used r a lot until now so I can't think of one.

I think I see at least one thing where I'm going wrong, or that at least should be improved: Do I need to assign individual names to the commands (e.g. nc_open(paste("'/specific_",df,"/data.nc',",sep="")))? I think it shouldnt solve the problem though, if it worked it would probably just overwrite the data that was read in earlier.

Comment: Do you mean `./specific_1/data.nc`?

Comment: Mh, no. It's just the path for the data, in the original it's a meter long so I put down a dummy here

Comment: `paste0("/specific_", df, "/data.nc")`

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!

Comment: The problem was that R didn't find the path. In future, you should make sure the path is indeed correct and make it the topic of your question. It's hard to debug path problems if you're referring to a pseudopath. :)